# filter data in table 1 that is not referenced in table 2 through foreign key in python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two tables table 1 and table 2, table 2 has a foreign key from table 1 in this case I intend to select all customers from table 1 that are not yet registered in table 2

models.py:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
  contador  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

---------**---------------------

```
 class Factura(models.Model):
      factura_nr  = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
      contador = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      estado_factura=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='Aberta',blank=True)
```

views.py

```
facturas_abertas2=Factura.objects.values('contador__contador').filter(data_leitura__month=date.today().month,estado_factura='Aberta')
    clientes=Cliente.objects.filter(contador=facturas_abertas2).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Count factura numbers and then filter out numbers greater than 0

```
clientes = Cliente.objects.annotate(factura_count=Count('factura__id')).filter(factura_count=0)
```